# Console output + Terminal on TFT

Tags: pi-3

I own an Adafruit 2.4" TFT display. Atm i installed the TFT in the latest Rasbian on my Pi 3b. I have HDMI connected to my desktop monitor and TFT is connected on GPIO header.

Now When my PI startsup, i see 4 fruits and some console boot on my desktop monitor. Halfway it switches over to my TFT, and Desktop gui is started on my TFT. On my desktop monitor, i see still the first part of the boot console. Its totally frozen on that monitor.

[image]

What i want is, that Desktop Gui (Startx) is runned on my Monitor (HDMI) and console/boot/terminal on my TFT.

Is this possible? Cant figure it out.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can run two usable monitors with standard Raspbian. [This discussion](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=661085#p661085) on the raspberrypi.org forums seems to suggest that it's achievable with a tweaked kernel.

Comment: That topic is more about the same thing on both devices. What i want is kinda different. –

Comment: Tried to play with export FRAMEBUFFER=/dev/fb1. Doesnt work either.